# Adwords conversion tracking for android using Appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, google-ads-api

Does anyone have an Appcelerator module for adwords conversion tracking for android? I already tried searching but only found module for iOS.

Comment: Is this a query about some error in your implementation of the Appcelerator module?

Comment: i just asking if theres a module for google adwords conversion tracking for appcelerator

Answer (score 0):

You can use this titanium module for AdWords Conversion tracking on Android:

https://github.com/annakozy2011/AdWordsAndroid